# Matlab tool/program to benchmark processes to assess improvement between 2013b and 2014a due to worker limit removal

Tags: matlab, benchmarking, stress-testing, worker

We are upgrading from Matlab 2013b to 2014a and getting some benchmark comparisons would be great to see how our performance will increase now there is no worker limit e.g. running with 12 workers compared to 32 or 64.

Is there a good demo or tool that can be used here to give a visual output that can be compared together?

Comment: The performance highly depends on the tasks you are running. Use your actual code to benchmark the differences, this is the only reliable benchmark for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several benchmarks shipping with Parallel Computing Toolbox: http://www.mathworks.com/help/distcomp/examples/index.html#benchmarks

As @Daniel says though, the best benchmark is your actual code because the speedup you will get depends on where the bottlenecks are as you add more workers (amount of memory, contention for memory access, CPU load limits...)

Comment: I am not sure how I missed this page.. Exactly what I need! Testing with our actual code will follow in the future, but there are a number of constraints that make it impossible to do so at the present.